# How to get below response using Retrofit GET method with RxJava

Tags: android, api, retrofit, rx-java, response

```
{"success":true,"rates": {"AT": {"country_name":"Austria","standard_rate":20,"reduced_rates": {"domestic flights":13,"entrance to sporting events":13,"admissions to cultural events and amusement parks":13,"firewood":13,"agricultural supplies":13}},"BE": {"country_name":"Belgium","standard_rate":21,"reduced_rates": {"some foodstuffs":12,"certain agricultural supplies":12,"social housing":12}}}}
```

I tried,

```
@GET("rate_list")
fun getValidCountries(
    @Query("access_key") accessKey: String,
) : Single<Response<JsonElement>>
```

But getting error like,

Cannot construct instance of `com.google.gson.JsonElement` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
at [Source: (okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader); line: 1, column: 1]

How to solve this, also i'm using RxJava to call API.

Answer (score 0):

In your code swap

```
@GET("rate_list")
fun getValidCountries(@Query("access_key") accessKey: String) : Single<Response<JsonElement>>
```

With this

```
@GET("rate_list")
fun getValidCountries(@Query("access_key") accessKey: String) : Single<ValidCountries>
```

Use [this](https://www.json2kotlin.com/) to create data classes for your JSON. And rename the class named `Json4Kotlin_Base` to `ValidCountrie(s)`

ALso, you don't need `Response` use catch to catch any `HttpException`.

Comment: I tried this already but its create diff. data classes for AT, BE and my response having 30 countries, so it will create 30 data classes

Comment: You can use HashMap<String, CountryBody> instead of creating 30 data classes

Comment: @ZhandarbekDzhalankuzov with data classes it's more readable. Easy to debug.

Comment: @AkshayKondekar if you need 30 classes better come up with some abstraction.

Comment: I'm trying getting response in string like, Single<String> and then convert into JsonObject